# Loud Click sound from left brake

Tags: brakes, brake-rotor, brake-calipers

My Left brake makes a loud click sound at low speed when I apply brakes. I have taken it to three different garages and got changed front both sides (L&R) calipers, brakes, shimmers,brake disks and caliper carriers. The brake pads and shimmers were changed twice in 2 months and the click sound persists. No mechanic is able to fix the click sound despite changing all the essential components of the braking system. I am getting frustrated now. The garages I have taken my car to are of good repute and the mechanics are experienced, but no one can figure out the cause of the click sound from the left brake. It's Chevrolet Cruze saloon 1.6 model 2009.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Wheel bearings, CV joints, the backing plates, tie rod ends, upper and lower ball joints, even the tires/wheels themselves could be the problem here.  It's really hard to know for sure.  Check everything!

Comment: Is it just one click each time you apply the brakes, or does it repeat?

Comment: Possibly the pads are moving in the caliper - been known to cause sounds like that before.

Answer (score 0):

Unable to add a comment due to low rep therefore responding through these means.

If you are getting an issue at low speeds. May be worth a go, to try replicate the issue. Whereby the car being on a lift, get someone to spin your front wheels (if it's coming from that region) applying the brakes lightly to try and pin point where exactly the noise is coming from?

Not sure about your braking system/make up of it. Potentially also worth a look, maybe have a look at your parking brake cable/linkage, do you have rear drum or disc brakes?

Personally I messed up a sort of holder on my right side parking brake cable when removing my rear brake disc and pad nearly two years ago. The cable goes through a middle insert before being attached to the rear brake system. Sometimes when I apply the brakes it "catches" which at times makes a similar sound, so the issue could be in a related system and not just the direct brake system where apparent.